# Sitecore Form 9.2. submit data trasfer

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a Sitecore 9.2 form that is created with 2 Pages, The submit button on the first form redirects to the next page,
I need to display some text information on the second form based on some processing results on submission. I know it should be a custom action, but where this custom action should keep data for the second form page.
How to do it in a proper way ?

in other words, if first page has user name field how to display this value at secong page

is Session good solutions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know is that data cannot be shared between pages by default.
You could however create a custom form processinig feature

```
<processor type="YOURPROJECT.Feature.FormsProcessing.Pipelines.FormsPipeline.FormProcessorFieldValue, YOURPROJECT.Feature.FormsProcessing" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.GetModel.CreateModel, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc']" resolve="true">
```

On your second page you can add a `hidden field` with a token variable.
With the Form processor you can check the field if it matches you overwrite the token value with the submitted field value.

A small example for reference that could work:

```
public class FormProcessorFieldValue: MvcPipelineProcessor<GetModelEventArgs> {
public override void Process(GetModelEventArgs args)
        {
// This token replacement is only valid on form fields that inherit from hiddenViewModel
        if (!(args.ViewModel is HiddenViewModel hiddenViewModel)) return;

        ReplaceTokensIfApplicable(hiddenViewModel, fieldId);
}
protected virtual void ReplaceTokensIfApplicable(HiddenViewModel hiddenViewModel, ID fieldId)
{
if (fieldId == new ID("{Field ID from submitted field}"))
{
    // Get the value of the of previous page field
    var textField = _formRenderingContext.GetPostedField(fieldId) as ListViewModel;
    string selectedOption = textField == null ? string.Empty : textField.Value.FirstOrDefault();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedOption))
    {
        //Set token in hidden field with submitted value
        if (hiddenViewModel.ItemId.ToLower() == "FIELD ID ON SECOND PAGE OF HIDDEN FIELD".ToLower())
        {
            hiddenViewModel.Value = selectedOption;
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Then you should be able to use conditions on you page based on the hidden field.

Hope it helps you in some way.